# Get the last data from if inside for loop

Tags: php

What I'm looking for is looking for logic that allows you to print horizontal rulers between content, except for the last content block, which you do NOT want to close with a horizontal ruler.

I have this code to loop the number from 1 to 10 and I have this if inside to check if number is stored in database.

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i == $class->Check($i)){
        echo $i;
        echo "<hr>"; // if not the last!
    }
}
```

I want to check here if it is the last data with the if condition not the loop, so if we got from if and the loop the numbers  2,3,4,7, I want to check with another if condition if it is the last number and print something.

Notice -> the for loop numbers isn't the same it's a variable this is just an example.

What is the code for (I have this loop and when if condition is true it print something then a hr tag, but I don't want the lase print to print a hr tag so I want to check if it is the last print with if condition to stop it from printing the tag).

Comment: Use different variable names? `$i` and `$SUPERVARIABLE` for example?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AksenP I can't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I want to check with another if condition if it is the last number not to print it.

Comment: it would be great if you could show us the expected vs. actual outcome and where you are stuck? What is your question - clarify with an example? Give us some context so we might be able to understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to retrieve the last saved number in the database. If this is the case, there are functions in MySQL, PostGRES to retrieve this value; you even have the option of the MAX function....

Comment: @jibsteroos I added what is the code for.

Comment: So, you are basically looking for logic that allows you to print horizontal rulers between content, except for the last content block, which you do NOT want to close with a horizontal ruler? I suggest you put this at the top of your question, because it will allow volunteers to actually post a possible solution to your issue.

Comment: @jibsteroos Yes, cause there is nothing after it.

Comment: @jibsteroos I added it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your condition, you can save your output in an array, **instead of displaying it immediatly**, and then, you can use it later, by checking if you are at the last value :

```
$MyOutput = [];

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    if($i == $class->Check($i)){
        $MyOutput[] = $i;
    }
}

for($i = 0, $len = count($MyOutput); $i < $len; $i++)
{
    echo $MyOutput[$i];
    if ($i == $len - 1) // are we at the last element ?
    {
        // your special message for the last element
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna a solution to make like this code but inside the first loop, not making another loop.

Comment: @GamalMohamed, his first loop imitates your content. It's not for you, it needs for an example. You need the second one.